# Angular 2 - 5 - наследование компонента, подводные камни?

Tags: angular2, наследование, компоненты

Недавно обнаружил довольно интересный способ оптимизировать написание кода при разработке компонентов в Angular 2.3.0, дело в том что, начиная с этой версии появилась возможность наследовать компонент, наследуется всё кроме шаблона. Появилась возможность создать родительский компонент, где можно прописать все необходимые сервисы, переменные, функции общего назначения, а потом наследовать дочерний компонент, главный плюс это возможность управлять дочерними компонентами из родительского (очень актуально в большом проекте где компонентов очень много). Но почему-то такой подход я не встречал в примерах кода, а наткнулся на него только когда сам заинтересовался.

**Мой вопрос - нет ли подводных камней в использовании такого подхода? есть ли те кто успешно использовал наследование компонентов в своих проектах и остался этим доволен?**

Вот пример кода родительский компонент:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, NgModule, Input, Output, 
EventEmitter, HostBinding, HostListener, Injector } from 
'@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";

import { LogService, FlashMessagesService, UrlService, ListDTO, 
QueryParams, ComponentPreloader } from "../../shared";
import { ItemNotFound, DialogConfirm  } from '../block';
import { DialogService } from "ng2-bootstrap-modal";
import {GrantDTO} from '../grant';

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

@Component({
  selector: 'meta-data-component',
  template: ''
})
export class MetaDataComponent<T> implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

protected log: LogService;
protected flashMessage: FlashMessagesService;
protected url: UrlService;
protected route: ActivatedRoute;
protected router: Router;
protected translate: TranslateService;
protected dialogService: DialogService;
protected Grant = GrantDTO;

protected subscription: Subscription;

protected isLoading = true;
protected list: ListDTO<T>;
protected phraseNotFound = 'No data found';

@Input()
baseUrl: string = '';

constructor(injector: Injector) {
    this.log = injector.get(LogService);
    this.flashMessage = injector.get(FlashMessagesService);
    this.url = injector.get(UrlService);
    this.route = injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
    this.router = injector.get(Router);
    this.translate = injector.get(TranslateService);
    this.dialogService = injector.get(DialogService);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.log.debug(this, 'OnInit');
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.log.debug(this, 'OnDestroy');
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

}
```

Дочерний компонент:

```
import { Component, Injector } from "@angular/core";
import { MetaDataComponent } from "../block";
import { ListDTO } from "../../shared";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

import { ClientRestService } from './client.rest';
import { ClientDTO } from './client.dto';

@Component({
  selector: 'client-card',
  templateUrl: 'client.card.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client.card.scss']
})
export class ClientCard extends MetaDataComponent<ClientDTO> {

public query: string;
private phone: string;

constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    private restService: ClientRestService
) {
    super(injector);
}

ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
    //далее произвольный код

}

getCarTitle(car: any): string {
    return car.carType + (car.description ? ': ' + car.description : '');
}

}
```

Очень интересно ваше мнение. Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: вопрос все еще актуален?

Comment: Если есть свое мнение по вопросу, в любом случае будет интересно

Answer (score 1):

Наследовал компоненты из [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/), минимум 4 класса. Перебивал стили на SCSS вместо CSS, копировал шаблон, логика поднималась простым наследованием. Проблем нет, продакшн, интерфейсы жизненного цикла тоже отрабатывают.

Comment: Через гитхаб, опенсорс же. :) Там он был инлайновый, я его в файл вынес, разницы не увидел.

Comment: ааа понятно, я подумал речь идёт именно о наследовании шаблона родителя, дело в том что если исхитрится можно и до шаблона родительского компонента из дочернего добраться, здесь увидел такой пример [https://stackoverflow.com/a/38077209/5533633], но он показался мне костыльным, да и острой необходимости в этом пока нет, подумал может у вас ещё какой вариант

Comment: В целом тоже имеет право на жизнь, если нет возможности добраться до исходников.

Comment: А стили родительского компонента как-то можно наследовать в дочерних?

Comment: Наследование стилей нет. По опыту работы пришёл к выводу что наилучшей практикой будет создание абстрактных классов или их иерархии, на основе этих классов можно создавать конечные компоненты, шаблоны у них будут свои, если необходимо чтобы оформление дочернего компонента зависело от родительского, то можно писать общие стили в main.scss например, или в scss родительского компонента.